# How Do I Use 'interval' With React, When converting From ES5 To ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval, intervals, es6-class

I didn't see anything pertinent in "Questions That May Already Have Your Answer" and researched 'facebook.github.io', but I'm confused on which way to use 'interval' in my case. I'm converting an ES5 App to an ES6 App in an online class. So, ES5 code is:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var GuineaPigs = require('../components/GuineaPigs');

var GUINEAPATHS = [
  'https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/React/react_photo-guineapig-1.jpg',
  'https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/React/react_photo-guineapig-2.jpg',
  'https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/React/react_photo-guineapig-3.jpg',
  'https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/React/react_photo-guineapig-4.jpg'
];

var GuineaPigsContainer = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return { currentGP: 0 };
  },

  nextGP: function () {
    var current = this.state.currentGP;
    var next = ++current % GUINEAPATHS.length;
    this.setState({ currentGP: next });
  },

  interval: null,

  componentDidMount: function () {
    this.interval = setInterval(this.nextGP, 5000);
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function () {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  },

  render: function () {
    var src = GUINEAPATHS[this.state.currentGP];
    return <GuineaPigs src={src} />;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <GuineaPigsContainer />, 
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

And, what I have, so far, in ES6 is:

```
import React from 'react'
import GuineaPigs from './GuineaPigs';

const GUINEAPATHS = [
  'https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/React/react_photo-guineapig-1.jpg',
  'https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/React/react_photo-guineapig-2.jpg',
  'https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/React/react_photo-guineapig-3.jpg',
  'https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/React/react_photo-guineapig-4.jpg'
];

class GuineaPigsContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { currentGP: 0 };
    this.nextGP = this.nextGP.bind(this);
  }

  nextGP () {
    let current = this.state.currentGP;
    let next = ++current % GUINEAPATHS.length;
    this.setState({ currentGP: next });
  }

  setInterval () {
    null
  }

}

export default GuineaPigsContainer;
```

I'm looking for pointers on how to handle this example, and maybe even pointers to docs on this subject. Thanks for any help provided.

Comment: How about doing it exactly the same way? With exactly the same `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ES5 above is written to ES6 as below ; anyway it is setInterval issue or any issue :

## ES6 :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import GuineaPigs from '../components/GuineaPigs';

var GUINEAPATHS = [
  'https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/React/react_photo-guineapig-1.jpg',
  'https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/React/react_photo-guineapig-2.jpg',
  'https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/React/react_photo-guineapig-3.jpg',
  'https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/React/react_photo-guineapig-4.jpg'
];

class GuineaPigsContainer extends React.Component {
   constructor() {
       super(...arguments); //⚠️Do not forget this line
       this.state = { currentGP: 0 };
       this.interval = null;
    }


  nextGP() {
    var current = this.state.currentGP;
    var next = ++current % GUINEAPATHS.length;
    this.setState({ currentGP: next });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(this.nextGP, 5000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  render() {
    var src = GUINEAPATHS[this.state.currentGP];
    return <GuineaPigs src={src} />;
  }
}
```

## ES7/ Babel :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import GuineaPigs from '../components/GuineaPigs';

var GUINEAPATHS = [
  'https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/React/react_photo-guineapig-1.jpg',
  'https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/React/react_photo-guineapig-2.jpg',
  'https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/React/react_photo-guineapig-3.jpg',
  'https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/React/react_photo-guineapig-4.jpg'
];

class GuineaPigsContainer extends React.Component {

   // no need constructor
   state = { currentGP: 0 };
   interval = null;
 // non-static methods
  nextGP() {
    var current = this.state.currentGP;
    var next = ++current % GUINEAPATHS.length;
    this.setState({ currentGP: next });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(this.nextGP, 5000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  render() {
    var src = GUINEAPATHS[this.state.currentGP];
    return <GuineaPigs src={src} />;
  }
}
```

Comment: You've lost the constructor.

Comment: And now - you've lost `super()`

Comment: And you don't need `...arguments` in the `super`. Not sure what you mean by ES7 though :-S

Comment: ES7 .. see now the updated answer to understand the difference